# Wordpress Page Parent Template

Tags: wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress site in which there are four main parent pages which have many subpages.

I have different layout for each parent page. Is there any way I can define that every parent page will use its own template. For example I have parent_page1.php, parent_page2.php, parent_page3.php and parent_page4.php templates in my theme folder. Now I can get the parent page ID but dont know how to define the condition for each page.

Kindly reply,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to do this automatically? If you're happy to let it be manual, you can just select the appropriate template from the Pages->Edit Page right column, that way each will have its own template, and you don't need any coding for that.